# Do we really need to implicitly convert ranges adaptors to bool?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

Since [`ranges::view_interface`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface) has an [`explicit operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view_interface/operator_bool) function, this makes most C++20 ranges adaptors have the ability to convert to `bool`:

https://godbolt.org/z/ccbPrG51c

```
static_assert(views::iota(0));
static_assert("hello"sv | views::split(' '));
static_assert(views::single(0) | std::views::transform([](auto) { return 0; }));
```

Although this seems very convenient, do we really need this feature? The reason is that traditional STL containers such as `std::vector`, or commonly used views such as `std::string_view`, do not have this functionality of converting to `bool`, which seems to have some inconsistencies. And it seems more intuitive to just call `.empty()` or `ranges::empty` directly to determine whether a range is empty.

In addition, this implicit conversion *maybe* also causes confusion:

```
static_assert(!views::empty<int>);
```

So, why does `ranges::view_interface` provide this `operator bool` function? Are there any practical use cases?

Please note that this may be an opinion-based question, but I want to know the philosophy behind `view_interface` providing `operator bool`.

Comment: Sounds like a question for Eric Niebler.  (Does Eric frequent this Q&A exchange?)

Comment: `bool` operators are considered harmful when they are implicit. This one is `explicit` so I personally see no problem on this front. On the matter of consistency with the other containers you have a point, however imho there is no issue on adding a convenient operator that doesn't exist on containers. I would maybe have seen a problem if they would have modified the semantics of an existing operation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From this [blog post](https://ericniebler.com/2018/12/05/standard-ranges) by Eric Niebler, whose range-V3 library heavily influenced C++20 ranges

> ... custom view types can inher[i]t from `view_interface` to get a host of useful member functions, like `.front()`, `.back()`, `.empty()`, `.size()`, `.operator[]`, and **even an explicit conversion to `bool` so that view types can be used in if statements**
>
> ```
> // Boolean conversion operator comes from view_interface:
> if ( auto evens = vec | view::filter(is_even) ) {
>   // yup, we have some evens. Do something.
> }
> ```

So this is at least one use case for converting a range view to `bool`. Note that this is an explicit conversion, so it only happens in a context that performs the conversion, e.g. by casting explicitly, or using it in an `if` condition, or in a `static_assert` as you have in your question.

---

As mentioned by Eric on a comment on this answer, this feature is not actually useful any longer for the stated use case, presumably since we now have if-with-initializers as a language construct, and so this feature could be deprecated.

Comment: It seems to be a simplification of `if (auto evens = vec | view::filter(is_even); !evens.empty())`.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Yes, that's true. Frankly, I don't see much use for this feature at the moment (and I haven't used it myself). It's true that the motivating case with the `if` condition is mostly reduced given if-with-initializers, but the ranges library was designed well before if-with-initializers were added to the language.

Comment: Yeah, it's not needed anymore, and could be deprecated.

Comment: Pretty much _every_ `explicit operator bool` can be spelled differently; that doesn't make them not useful. I've certainly found this one to be convenient on a number of occasions - and not having to write a negation makes it less error-prone.

Comment: @T.C. Hmm, that's fair. Perhaps I should give it a spin, and see how it feels. The point about not needing to write a negation being less error-prone certainly makes sense.